# Hyperplane sections of curves in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

Let $K$ be an algebraically close field, and let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^2(k)$ be an irreducible  curve of degree $d$. We know that a general  line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ intersects $X$ in 
$d$ distinct points. Actually, if $X$ is not strange, we also know something stronger:

*For any $P \in \mathbb{P}^2$, the general  line in the $\mathbb{P}^1$
of lines contaning $P$  intersects $X$ in 
$d$ distinct points.*

I was wondering if  something analogous for  curves in higher dimensional spaces holds. More precisely, I asked myself the following question:

Consider a  curve (say,irreducible, smooth)  $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d>n$. What is the largest number $r$ such that for any   set of points  $\{P_1,\cdots,P_r\}$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the property that a general  hyperplane in the family of all hyperplanes containing the points $P_1,\cdots,P_r$ intersects $X$ in  $d$ distinct points?

My (naive) guess is $r=n-1$, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: By your correction, you have made my answer look silly, but even worse, you made your question worse. For example, in 3-space, general hyperplanes containing a general line will have this property and then you can take infinitely many points on this line.

Comment: Fair enough! It is back to the original.

Comment: I hope you have realized by now what the correct statement should be. Do not take points, but take the linear space generated by them. So, the correct statement is the largest dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that the general hyperplane containing it meets your curve in $d$ points is $n-2$.

Comment: Your comments were very enlightening, and  your statement makes much more sense.    I'm still puzzled with the n-2 answer, though. I keep thinking
that it is somewhat related to the fact that the general linear space of dimension n-2 will not meet the curve. But I'm still struggling to connect things up.

Comment: Dear Mohan, here is what my intuition says...It is hard to formalize it, but  I'll be happy if this makes sense:

A general linear space of dimension $n-2$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is  generated by a (general) set of $n-1$ linearly indenpendent  points. The latter ones are extended  to  (general) sets of $n$ linearly indenpendent  points, which, in turn,  correspond to general hyperplanes.

Comment: If you take a general $n-2$ plane, as you said, it doesn't intersect $C$ and so, the projection from this plane gives you a finite map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. So, avoiding "strange" curves (say char 0), the fiber over a general point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $d$ distinct points. But, this is precisely the intersection of the hyperplane generated by your $n-2$ plane and this point with your curve, which is a general hyperplane containing the $n-2$ plane intersected with your curve.

Comment: That is neat! Thanks a lot for all the patience and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r=1$ in all cases. If $r=2$ (similar arguments for $r>2$) then take two points on some tangent line to the curve. Then any hyperplane containing these will also contain the tangent line and thus tangential to the curve, giving smaller number of points of intersection.